React native build error : Command failed with exit code 9009: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -x lint -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
I cloned a React Native project and I try to run the command
yarn run android or adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 & set NODE_ENV=development & react-native run-android --list-devices --verbose
But I keep getting the following error
error Failed to build the app.
Error: Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -x lint -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
    at makeError (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:60:11)
    at module.exports.sync (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\execa\index.js:194:17)
    at build (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\buildAndroid\index.js:68:22)
    at runOnSpecificDevice (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:221:33)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:164:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\HUAWEI\WebstormProjects\Martines\application\client\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:118:9)
error Command failed with exit code 1.


My computer's OS is Windows 11, I've installed java SDK 22, added the env and path variables for both Java and Android.
I have no idea on what to do next. I already tryed that solution text
But I already have a settings file, that seems fine to me:
rootProject.name = 'LesMartines'
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
include ':app'
includeBuild('../node_modules/@react-native/gradle-plugin')


Thanks in advance !

The current version of React Native supports JDK version 17.
choco install -y nodejs-lts microsoft-openjdk17

Detailed instruction are here https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.73/environment-setup?os=windows

Thanks, I changed my JDK to 17 but still got the error. RN doctor tells me that it can't find my Android SDK, but in local.properties, it's the right path.

I found the solutions !
First, thanks to the answer of Kirill, I changed the JDK to from 22 to 17,
Then, in android studio -> settings -> sdk -> sdk tools, I installed Android SDK command-line tools

Finally, I removed the ligne org.gradle.java.home from android roots project.
